# Return marker data from google maps to application

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

is it possible to have a click event open the google maps application for the user to set a marker and return that marker information to the application?

I'm creating a listview and list item click I want to open google maps application, the user can then place a marker and that marker is returned to the application to be stored in DB.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can try with this code.

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

You can access the place in onActivityResult method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

For further details check Android developer documentation for place picker